# Schedule Apex not working properly

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, cron

I have a batch that schedule a job for the next hour but in my Production environment is scheduling it for the following month.

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    Datetime now = Datetime.now().addHours(1);
    System.schedule(MyClass.class.getName() + ' ' + generateRandomString(6), '0 0 ' + now.hour() + ' ' + now.day() + ' * ?', new MyClass());
    AsyncApexJob aaj = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    System.abortJob(aaj.id);
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have in my org; generates a valid CRON expression for a given datetime. Note that the result will be a fully-specified date including the year

```
 0 34 5 29 12 ? 2021   // 0534h 2021-12-29
```

In a Util class

```
public static String getSchedulerCronExpression(Datetime dtIn) {
    DateTime dt     = dtIn == null ? now.addSeconds(10) : dtIn;
    return ('' + dt.second() + ' ' + dt.minute() + ' ' + dt.hour() + ' ' + dt.day() +
            ' ' + dt.month() + ' ? ' + dt.year());
}
```

Then my `finish()` method would look like

```
System.schedule(Myclass.class.getName() + ' ' + generateRandomString(6),
   Util.getSchedulerCronExpression(System.now().addHours(1));
...
```